# selecting all records between a certain period in mysql

Tags: mysql, time, between

I have the following table,for example:

```
id....name....fromtime....totime
1.....a.......00:00.......00:09:59
2.....a.......00:10.......00:19:59  
3.....a.......00:20.......00:29:59  
4.....a.......00:30.......00:39:59  
5.....a.......00:40.......00:49:59
```

I want to retrieve all records that belong to a (not a problem) and are between 00:05 and 00:25 that is, for the above example, are rows 1 to 3 leaving 4 and 5 out.

How can I accomplish that using mysql?
Thanks

Comment: [***Have you tried anything?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please post any queries you've tried so far. *Hint:* To filter dates and times you should use inequalities (`>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`)

Comment: I tried "between" and simple operators as you wrote but the "to" i'm looking for is not in the same row as the "from" I'm looking for so I'm getting an empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the 'between' clause with a new column that combines `fromtime` and `totime`.

For instance, `SELECT id, fromtime-totime As "elapsed_time" FROM your_table WHERE elapsed_time BETWEEN 5 AND 25`. Or something like that. The query will vary depending on the types of your columns.

See more here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm
http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/arithmetic-operations.php

Answer (score 0):

AND FromTime >= subtime( $time ) , '00:10:00' ) - to get also the first row

AND ToTime <= addtime( TIME( $time ) , '00:20:00' ) - 00:20:00 is an example ofcourse